# iframe is not working in iOS (ionic framework)

Tags: ios, iframe, ionic-framework

I developed an app with ionic framework for both iOS and Android. There is no problem in Android. But, iframe is not showing anything in iOS device and simulator although it works very well in Android and browser.
Please help me!  :)

Comment: hi, did you manage to solve this issue because i have this same problem?

Answer (score 45):

Try adding this to your config.xml file inside `<platform name="ios">` tags:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Had the same issue and it worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

Marco solution works great but allows any URL in your app iframes, so there could be security issues.

If you know the possible URLs of your iframes, limit the allow-navigation settings as below:

```
<allow-navigation href="https://*youtube.com*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*vimeo.com*" />
```

That will only let your approved URLs to be loaded in iframes.